# Properties of function $f(A) = \text{tr}(A^{2})$ on set of real matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

There is function $f$ on set $M$, such that
$$ f(A) = \text{tr}(A^{2}), \space M = \{A \in \text{Mat}_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R}) \space | \space A^{T} = A, \space \text{det} A \neq 0\} $$

Is it bounded below or above? If so, does it reach its min/max?

---

My ideas are the following:

Let $ A =  \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & c \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right) $. Since $\text{det} A \neq 0 $, we have $ad-c^{2} \neq 0 $. Our function is  $f(A) = \text{tr}(A^{2}) = a^2 + 2c^{2} + d^{2} $. It is bounded from below by zero, but can't reach its min because $a, c, d$ can't all equal zero at the same time since $ad-c^{2} \neq 0 $. It is not bounded from above because we can let $a = d = 0$ and any $ c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Is this a correct solution and does it fully answer to given questions?

Comment: Looks perfectly good.

Comment: Alternatively and more generally: symmetric matrices are diagonalizable, so they have a full set of eigenvalues, counting multiplicities; being invertible, $0$ is not an eigenvalue. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. And the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues. So if $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ (with multiplicity), then $\mathrm{tr}(A^2) = \lambda_1^2+\cdots+\lambda_n^2$; it follows that it is always positive but can be as small as you want, or as large as you want.

Comment: @Arturo, you might have wanted to mention that all those eigenvalues are *real*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Indeed; it should have read “**real** symmetric matrices are diagonalizable” or some such.